# Sum of product of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $\{a_n\},\ \{c_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a\in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n = 1$. Prove that

$$
\lim\limits_{M\to\infty} \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{M} c_n a_n = a
$$

Answer (score 0):

First show this is true if $c_n = 1$ for all $n$. Separately, show that if $\{d_n\}$ is another sequence with $d_n \to 0$ then $\frac 1 M \sum_1^M d_n a_n \to 0$. (Use the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and for any $\epsilon > 0$, all except a finite number of the $d_n$ satisfy $|d_n|<\epsilon$.)

Now put these two observations together and you are done.